# how to remove phtml file from home page in magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, home

How can I remove a phtml template file from my theme, but only from the home page?

My template file is "***custome_home.phtml***" at `app/design/frontend/kalpak/ktheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html`

Answer (score 0):

First,you should find `custome_home.phtml`  block  name layout files or from backedn,

then using `<referenceBlock name="BlockName" remove="true"/>` from lyaout.

**There are two way,you can do this:**

### *From admin*

Goto **admin>Content>Page>** then select your *cms pag*e>

and  after that *add below at code Design tab at  your CMS home page at backend*

```
<referenceContainer name="ParentContainerName">
     <referenceBlock name="BlocknameatLyaout" remove="true"/></referenceContainer>
```

### From Layout file:

Goto *app/design/frontend/[VendorTheme]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml* and below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
<!-- add this code for remove block -->
    <referenceBlock name="BlockName" remove="true"/>
    </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be complete this is how to overwrite a home page phtml fille from a theme :

**App/Design/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">

    <layout id="custom_home">
        <label translate="true">custom_home</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

This file is responsible for creating a custom page layout. You can set your page layouts in your Magento Admin section under **Content->Page->select page-> Design**

**App/Design/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

In this file you can decide your markup of the page. You can add or delete blocks or move container/blocks according to the default standards.
For example i needed to overwrite the `catalog.topnav` menu to create a Mega Menu and in my module that creates it i used (this can also be done in the theme) :

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" template="Designit_MegaMenu2::html/topmenu.phtml" class="Designit\MegaMenu2\Block\Html\MegaMenu">
</referenceBlock>
```

More info about that : [Custom Layout](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)

**Within this XML you can change template files from existing magento blocks or add blocks however you want.**

> Note : This is only true if you have Magento_Blank or something as a
>   parent which i highly recommend!
>
> Note 2 : A home page is not just 1 phtml file. It consists out of
>   different blocks and i really recommend adjusting these blocks. This
>   is the only correct way of theming your website